# Google Form creates Google Slides from template Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-slides

I have a script that on Form submit takes the data from the spreadsheet and creates a copy of a template and populates the google docs. I am trying to accomplish the same thing from google form to google slides.

First script I use for the google forms to google docs. The second script is my attempt of using the same principles and applying to google slides. My issue is I'm getting an error saying TypeError: values.forEach is not a function (line 109, file "Code") in relation to values.forEach(function(page). Any suggestions on how I could go about solving this?

Google Form to Google Sheets

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var address = e.values[1];
  var image = e.values[2];
  var price = e.values[3];
  var summary = e.values[4];
  var type = e.values[5];
  var year_built = e.values[6];
  var bed = e.values[7];
  var bath = e.values[8];
  var home_size = e.values[9];
  var lot_size = e.values[10];
  var occupancy = e.values[11];
 
var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxx");

var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("yyyyyyyyyy")

var copy = templateFile.makeCopy( address , templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())

var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText("{{address}}", address);
body.replaceText("{{price}}", price);
body.replaceText("{{summary}}", summary);
body.replaceText("{{type}}", type);
body.replaceText("{{year_built}}", year_built);
body.replaceText("{{beds}}", bed);
body.replaceText("{{baths}}", bath);
body.replaceText("{{home_size}}", home_size); 
body.replaceText("{{lot_size}}", lot_size);  
body.replaceText("{{occupancy}}", occupancy);   
  
  
doc.saveAndClose;

}
```

Google Form to Google Slides

```
function generateLandingPagesReport(){
  var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxx/edit"
  var Presentation_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
  var deck = SlidesApp.openById(Presentation_ID);
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getRange('A1:J17').getValues;
 
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var templateSlide = slides[1];
  var presLength = slides.length;
  
  values.forEach(function(page){
    
    values.forEach(function(page){
      if(page[0]){
        var landingPage = page[0];
        var sessions = page[1];
        var newSessions = page[2];
      }
      
   templateSlide.duplicate(); // duplicate the template page
   /*slides = deck.getSlides(); // update the slides array for indexes and length*/
   newSlide = slides[2]; // declare the new page to update
   
      
   var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
      shapes.forEach(function(shape){
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{landing page}}', landingPage);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{sessions}}', sessions);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{new sessions}}',newSessions);
      });
      
      presLength = slides.length;
      newSlide.move(presLength);
        //end our condition statement
        
      }); //close our loop of values
    
    //remove template slide
    
    templateSlide.remove();
    
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parenthesis when calling the getValue() method.

Change this:

`var values = sheet.getRange('A1:J17').getValues;`

To this:

`var values = sheet.getRange('A1:J17').getValues();`

Comment: Now I'm getting another  where it says theres an error with ````slides = deck.getSlides();```` but it's commented out. When I add it back in I get an error saying that Exception: Argument cannot be null: newText (line 34, file "Create!") ````shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{sessions}}', sessions);````

Comment: The error says `newText` cannot be null, but the snippet you posted doesn't have any mention of `newText`, so I cannot know how it is being used.

Comment: This is the full error I got                                                                             
Exception: Argument cannot be null: newText
    at [unknown function](Create!:34:25)
    at [unknown function](Create!:32:14)
    at [unknown function](Create!:16:12)
    at generateLandingPagesReport(Create!:14:10)  I don't have anything called newText in the code at all. Not sure why it says that. I've tried commenting out the ````shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{sessions}}', sessions);```` and the other shape.getText() and the same error comes up for all 3.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was looking for but this uses the first Row to identify the tag inside the Google slides template like {{title}} and replaces that with the value in the second row of the sheet

```
function createPresentation() {
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1YVEA4WtU1Kf6nZRgHpwnKBIR-V6rRN6s9zCdOQDkWNI");
  
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1k7rcfXODij4o4arSULuKZUHbit1m_X64");
  
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy("New" , templateResponseFolder);
  var Presentation = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());
      
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getValues();
  
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    var templateVariable = row[0];
    var templateValue = row[1];
    
    Presentation.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have copy the template page, you work on it and try to do replace.

However, change may be pending such that `newSlide = slides[2];` give `undefined`.

You may need to try [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveAndClose()) before performing any actions.

```js
   templateSlide.duplicate(); // duplicate the template page
   /*slides = deck.getSlides(); // update the slides array for indexes and length*/

   /* flush the presentation */
   deck.saveAndClose();
   deck = SlidesApp.openById(Presentation_ID);
   slides = deck.getSlides();

   newSlide = slides[2]; // declare the new page to update
   
      
   var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
      shapes.forEach(function(shape){
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{landing page}}', landingPage);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{sessions}}', sessions);
        shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{new sessions}}',newSessions);
      });
```